# Override class variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have made a class Service. I am trying to run a Interval every X seconds. The default is 30 seconds. But I want to set a custom delay if needed in other classes. I can't find a way to override the variables in my parent class.

```
class Service {
    
    delay = 30;

    constructor(api, client = undefined) {
        this.api = api;
        this.client = client;
        this.handle();
    }

    getMiliSeconds() {
        return this.delay * 1000;
    }

    service = async () => {
        // Service to run in background
    }

    handle() {
        setInterval(() => { this.service() }, this.getMiliSeconds());
    }
}

module.exports = Service;
```

When I extend the class Service I am trying to override the `delay` variable

```
class Notification extends Service {

    delay = 60;

    service = async () => {
        // I am not running every 60 seconds.
    }
}

module.exports.Notification = Notification;
```

However the Interval function is still runned every 30 seconds. Instead of the 60 seconds I set in the Notifications class.

Comment: Sure, in my main file I instantiate them like this: `let services = [new Notification(api, client), new Receiver(api, client)];`

Comment: Read this article https://javascript.info/class-inheritance#overriding-class-fields-a-tricky-note

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that super constructors run before child constructors run or assign to instances. For example:

```
class Parent {
  prop = 'foo'
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.prop);
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  prop = 'bar'
}
```

will always log `foo`, because the class field `prop = 'bar'` will only run after the parent constructor finishes and control flow is yielded back to the child.

When you call `this.handle` in the super constructor, `getMiliSeconds` runs immediately, retrieving the delay before the child has had a chance to assign its own `delay` to the instance.

To fix it, I'd move `this.handle` out of the constructor, so that it can be called on demand after the object is fully instantiated, not before.

In the snippet below, the `delay = 1` in the child class is now successfully causing the child service to run every second, instead of every 3 seconds.

```js
class Service {    
    delay = 3;
    constructor(api, client = undefined) {
        this.api = api;
        this.client = client;
    }
    getMiliSeconds() {
        return this.delay * 1000;
    }
    service = async () => {
        console.log('parent service');
        // Service to run in background
    }
    handle() {
        setInterval(() => { this.service() }, this.getMiliSeconds());
    }
}

class Notification extends Service {
    delay = 1;
    service = async () => {
        console.log('child service');
    }
}


const n = new Notification();
n.handle();
```

Another approach would be to put the `delay` property on the prototype, instead of as a class field (which is equivalent to inside the constructor - and the time that the relative constructors are permitted to run is the problem):

```js
class Service {    
    constructor(api, client = undefined) {
        this.api = api;
        this.client = client;
        this.handle();
    }
    getMiliSeconds() {
        return this.delay * 1000;
    }
    service = async () => {
        console.log('parent service');
        // Service to run in background
    }
    handle() {
        setInterval(() => { this.service() }, this.getMiliSeconds());
    }
}
Service.prototype.delay = 3;

class Notification extends Service {
    service = async () => {
        console.log('child service');
    }
}
Notification.prototype.delay = 1;


const n = new Notification();
```

Comment: I didn't realized that but it makes perfectly sense. Thank you! Would it be possible to override the constructor and change the delay there and then call the super() method to call the parents constructor?

Comment: No, I don't think so, not in any good way. Child classes just can't interact with the instance at all before the parent's `super` has finished.